# How can I select elements outside of my component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I have two LWCs that I have put in a community page. I wanted to select an element of the other LWC from the other LWC, which I currently do not know how.

So, basically, my question is that, is there a way we can select an element in LWC1 from LWC2?

In native JavaScript, I believe this is how it's done:

```
document.querySelector('.some-classname');
```

But I've tried it in LWC and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

By design, see e.g. [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom), that is not possible.

Edit your question to say exactly *what* you are aiming to do here between the two LWCs as *how* best to do that can depend on that.

Typically for LWCs that are not directly related, and assuming you have control over both LWCs, use the [Lightning Message Service](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-between-unrelated-components) when the LWCs are running in the normal Salesforce desktop.

For Communities (AKA Digital Experiences), in the past you had to use a separate pub/sub library for this (works fine, just extra code to add), but LMS was in beta for Communities in May 2021, so may be GA by now or GA soon.